# ember-composable-helpers checkbox not checking

Tags: ember.js

I'm using composable helpers in Ember.  When I click the parent checkbox, all of the children checkboxes check and uncheck, but the parent never shows a checkmark.  What am I missing here?

Parent: `<input type="checkbox" checked={{allSelected}} {{action (toggle "allSelected" this)}}>`

Children: `<input type="checkbox" checked={{allSelected}}>`

Answer (score 0):

The `{{action}}` helper [can not prevent the click action from bubbling up](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.8/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/action?anchor=action) when used in this style (closure by providing a function). A few ways I can think of to solve this in older ember versions. (with ember octane you would just use the `{{on}}` helper which doesn't suffer from the same limitations).

1. Do the toggle in an action in the component's backing JS and pass `{{action "toggle"}}` to stop the bubbling of the event.
2. Split up your input with `{{if}}`.

```
{{if this.allSelected}}
  <input checked>
{{else}}
  <input>
{{/if}}
```

*Old somewhat wrong answer:*

I'm not 100% sure what is happening here (it may have to do with the browser double applying your click). I think switching to a more recent ember action handling syntax may fix this.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={{this.allSelected}} {{on "click" (toggle "allSelected" this)}}>
```

Or on older versions of ember (before `{{on}}` was introduced)

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={{this.allSelected}} {{action (toggle "allSelected" this) on="click"}}>
```

If that doesn't work you may want to give the built in [input](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.22.0/components/built-in-components/#toc_input) component a try as it smooths out some of the rough edges on events.

Comment: that throws this error:  Compile Error on is not a modifier: Helpers may not be used in the element form.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you're using a version of ember before the on modifier was introduced. I added the information on binding the action helper to a specific event.

Comment: That changed the error message to : Assertion Failed: <tm-proto@component:orders-workflow/select-bank::ember262> had no action handler for: click

Comment: Sorry, I freehanded that and used the wrong syntax. I corrected it above, but also did some more poking around in the docs and maybe figured out the root cause of your issue.